# Kafka Connect : test.sink.txt is not getting updated after running connectors and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have tried to input data into Kafka connect-test topic using below steps. I was able to consume topic once and on second attempt with new file, I am unable to get data consumed. Output file `test.sink.txt` is not getting updated

1. `echo -e "foo\nbar" > test.txt`
2. `bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties config/connect-file-sink.properties`
3. `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic connect-test --from-beginning`

   ```
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 kafka kafka     8 Jan 27 20:41 test.txt
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 kafka kafka     0 Jan 27 20:42 test.sink.txt
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue is answered here : [Kafka connect tutorial stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007735/kafka-connect-tutorial-stopped-working)

The Kafka file source connect keeps the last read location from file.
When you deleted the file without resetting the offsets to 0, connector waits for new data to show starting at a specific character count from the beginning.

If you are using stand alone mode deleting  /tmp/connect.offsets will solve the issue.

Comment: How to delete /tmp/connect.offsets. I cant find this on my Windows system.